# Replacing front struts on a 2006 Hyundai Sonata

Tags: suspension, hyundai, sonata

I want to replace the front strut shocks on my 2006 Hyundai Sonata and I'm not sure if I'll need a spring compresser to do this. I have searched the internet for an answer to this question and I haven't had any luck. Anyone have any experience performing this repair on this particular vehicle. I know that sometimes you need the compresser and sometimes you don't.
Thanks.
Larry

Answer (score 4):

Yes a Spring Compressor Tool is required to change that strut.

Here is a picture of the strut, based on this design you will have to use the spring compressor for replacement.

[image]

Comment: BTW, it took me a minute to realize that you weren't just talking to yourself....

Answer (score 2):

If you check with your supplier some sell a loaded strut.It comes with a new spring and strut mount.If you don't have a strut compressor or are unlikely to have a need for one again it can make sense to spend the extra money and save a lot of time.